# Java Servlet: Specify postdata limit for request.getParameter?

Tags: java, servlets, post, limit

I understand that the first call to `getParameter` will read the postdata content, if any.

Is there a way for me to limit how much postdata content would be processed into the RAM, or am I going to need to override the `getParameter*` methods for that to be accomplished?

I am not interested in making this a server-wide setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *or am I going to need to override the getParameter* methods for that to be accomplished?*

Yes.

For that you can use a homegrown [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) which is injected by a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info).

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(new MyPostDataLimitingRequest((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there is a way to limit through the existing `getParameter()`, which is a convenience method, without extending the servlet or adding a listener to break it down for you.

You can circumvent this by parsing the input stream within your servlet directly using `getInputStream()` or `getReader()`, but I believe this invalidates further calls to `getParameter()` for the rest of that request; you'll need to consume the rest of the input through your selected method.

It's not elegant, but it works.